# Rank one constraint in optimization, which is nonconvex, but will we find the global maximum?

Tags: optimization

The objective function is $L = D(B)$, here $D$ is a function of $B$ and $D$ is a convex function. We have a prior information of $B$: it is rank one and we can write $B$ into $B = pq^T$. So we can change the objective function into $L=D(p, q)$. Obviously, for $p$ and $q$, this problem is not a convex problem anymore and we can have many sets of $p$ and $q$. My question is that even though we have a lot of local minimum regarding $p$ and $q$, will we have a global minimum $B$ even though there are many $p$ and $q$? Thanks so much for your answering.